WARNING: Detected flash encryption enabled and download manual encrypt disabled
I'm trying to upload a code to my esp32, but i am having this errores. I already tried with --force, deleting the flash, and none of above have function, can someone please help me?

Sketch uses 280941 bytes (21%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 20256 bytes (6%) of dynamic memory, leaving 307424 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
esptool.py v4.6
Serial port COM7
Connecting....
Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision v3.0)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: c0:49:ef:f5:17:f8
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...


A fatal error occurred: WARNING: Detected flash encryption enabled and download manual encrypt disabled.
Flashing plaintext binary may brick your device! Use --force to override the warning.
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2


According to this thread, one option is to disable encryption (permamently) by burning the corresponding e-fuse
